# My linux pc is corrupted and showing this error "error: no such device: a029261a"

Tags: grub2

My linux pc is corrupted and showing this error "error: no such device: a029261a" How can I get my saved documents back please tell me or restore the files.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot from Ubuntu LiveUSB and copy all your files anywhere you like, if your HDD is still alive.